# WooCommerce custom checkout checkboxes fields validation for one mandatory checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, paypal-subscriptions

I have three custom checkout fields, and people have to check at least one for the order to go through.
This is only needed for 1 product.

So, I loop through the cart items to check if the product is in the cart, then add the fields. This part works fine:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'mmm_add_custom_checkout_field' );

function mmm_add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) { 
    
       $product_id = 214884;
   $in_cart = false;
  
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
      if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true;
   }
  
   if ( $in_cart ) {
    echo '<h2>Membership Application</h2>';
    echo '<p>Select all that applies</p>';
   woocommerce_form_field( 'read_wog', array(        
      'type' => 'checkbox',        
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ), 
       'required' => true,
      'label' => 'I accept term 1', 
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'read_wog' ) ); 
        woocommerce_form_field( 'one_on_one', array(        
      'type' => 'checkbox',        
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ),
      'required' => true,
      'label' => 'I accept term 2', 
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'one_on_one' ) ); 
        woocommerce_form_field( 'mm_sn', array(        
      'type' => 'checkbox',
      'required' => true,
      'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ),        
      'label' => 'I accept term 3).', 
   ), $checkout->get_value( 'mm_sn' ) ); 

      
  
   }

}
```

The site uses Paypal Express as a payment gateway, and the validation lets people go through Paypal regardless of the checkbox validation. The validation for default fields works fine. The error notice is added when manually refreshing the page though!

Here's the validation code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'mmm_validate_new_checkout_field' );
  
function mmm_validate_new_checkout_field() {    
   $product_id = 214884;
   $in_cart = false;
  
   foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
      $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
      if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true;
   }
     if( $in_cart && !isset($_POST['mm_sn']) && !isset($_POST['one_on_one']) && !isset($_POST['read_wog']) ) {
         wc_add_notice( 'You can only have a full membership if you accept at least 1 term', 'error' );
     }
}
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The site uses PayPal Express as a payment gateway"

This isn't specific enough to be able to advise. If PayPal JS SDK buttons are being used (called smart buttons in the WooCommerce PayPal plugin configuration), then you can add an `onClick` handler as documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#oninitonclick

You'll need to edit the outputted JS of how the WooCommerce plugin invokes `paypal.Buttons` to include such a function.

Comment: Thanks. How could I make it more specific? It's the official PayPal checkout extension. I would've thought that if the standard validations work, they could be extended via standard woocommerce actions to do custom validations as well.

Comment: Only JS in `onClick` will affect what happens after the PayPal buttons are rendered

Comment: Relevant section: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/blob/85a478de146459418b23854cca4a60f073344dbf/assets/js/wc-gateway-ppec-smart-payment-buttons.js#L211 -- it's a JS file, there's no woocommerce action php

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to validate with JS then.

Answer (score 1):

The following revisited code will throw an error validation message if at least one checkbox has not been checked on checkout:

```
// Custom function that check if a specific product is in cart
function is_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $product_id, array($item['product_id'], $item['variation_id']) ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Add Custom checkout checkboxes fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'mmm_add_custom_checkout_field' );
function mmm_add_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $targeted_id = 214884;

    if ( is_product_in_cart( $targeted_id ) ) {
        echo '<h2>Membership Application</h2>
            <p>Select all that applies</p>';
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'read_wog', array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'I accept term 1',
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'read_wog' ) );
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'one_on_one', array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'I accept term 2',
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'one_on_one' ) );
        
        woocommerce_form_field( 'mm_sn', array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array( 'form-row-wide no-req' ),
            'label' => 'I accept term 3).',
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'mm_sn' ) );
    }
}

// Custom checkout checkboxes fields validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'mmm_validate_new_checkout_field' );
function mmm_validate_new_checkout_field() {
    $targeted_id = 214884;

    if ( is_product_in_cart( $targeted_id ) && ! ( isset($_POST['read_wog']) || isset($_POST['one_on_one']) || isset($_POST['mm_sn']) ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( 'You can only have a full membership if you accept at least 1 term', 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this still doesn't do the validation with the official PayPal Checkout plugin on my setup. It goes through to Paypal and only adds a notice after page refresh. Would you mind telling me what payment gateway did you use? https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/

Comment: Yes. I was under the same impression. And itt does work with different payment methods such as Stripe. But I've just tried without any additional plugins on the default theme and it did not work with Paypal checkout

Comment: @lastnoob Apparently paypal-checkout uses javascript for validation and **doesn't handle custom checkout fields validation**. I don't have enough knowledge related to paypal-checkout to make it work with it.